# Related to compilation error in solidity when using multiple parameter in constructor

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

CompilerError: Stack too deep. Try compiling with `--via-ir` (cli) or the equivalent `viaIR: true` (standard JSON) while enabling the optimizer. Otherwise, try removing local variables. When compiling inline assembly: Variable dataEnd is 1 slot(s) too deep inside the stack.

```
constructor(address _escrow, uint256 _Presale_Start_Countdown, uint256 _Presale_End_Countdown,  uint256 _Softcap_End_Countdown, uint256 _Hardcap_End_Countdown, address _funder1, 
    address _funder2, address _funder3, address _Development, address _Marketing, address _Community, address _TokenStability, uint256 _DropTokens ) public {
    Presale_Start_Countdown = _Presale_Start_Countdown;
    Presale_End_Countdown = _Presale_End_Countdown;
    require(_escrow != address(0));
    escrow = _escrow;
    DropTokens = _DropTokens;
    presaleSupply_ = 3000000000000000000000000;
    funder1 = _funder1;
    funder2 = _funder2;
    funder3 = _funder3;
    Development = _Development;
    Marketing = _Marketing;
    Community = _Community;
    TokenStability =_TokenStability;
    balance[escrow] += DropTokens;
    balance[escrow] += presaleSupply_;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why you get a lot of parameter in constructor?, i suggest you set important parameter in constructor then you can set other params by set methods also you can check you set function by owner only modifier

Comment: can you send any example in which only owner modifier used. if we use only owner modifier is this will pass only by admin

Comment: it's simple you just need to store your admin address in variable when constructor fire, then you can define a modifier like this  ` modifier _ownerOnly(){
      require(msg.sender == owner);
}`